# Do any Amazon S3 clients allow automation for setting expiration headers?

Tags: software-recommendation, chrome-extensions

I am using [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit) and the Firefox extension [S3 Organiser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/amazon-s3-organizers3fox/).   Neither completely satisfies my requirements  as both tools lack the ability to set an expiration header.

This makes me cry, as I need to manually run a script to download files to a local machine, use an S3 API to set the expiration header, then upload the files back to the S3 server.  This is time consuming.

Does anyone know of a tool or client for Mac that allows the user to specify an expiration header?

Comment: Have you shot off a support email to the very fine folks at Panic? Perhaps linking to your query here if you feel the discussion will add to your request. I have been delighted with the support I get from them whenever Transmit causes me to scratch my head.

Comment: As to your question, have you tried mounting the S3 files using Transmit and just running your script as if the filesystem were local?

Comment: mounting does not help as the expiration header is purely for HTTP request header only (which you can't set in normal file system)

Comment: See this tweet from Panic - Transmit can do this: https://twitter.com/willco007/statuses/231744013009555456

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if it meets your needs, but [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) allows you to set the Cache-Control header. See [this link](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/s3) for more information (see the section on **Cache Control Setting**).

Comment: For outbound links Cyberduck can 100% do this. For any object in a bucket you right click and you can generate that has a signed policy embedded in it. You can customize the available time outs. See: http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/s3#SignedtemporaryURLs for the details.

Comment: 3q, I quite happy with the software, despite the connection handling is quite slow (bearable)

Answer (score 1):

Transmit can do this.

Preferences > Cloud allows you to set custom headers on upload for all files or by extension.

Set `Expires` HTTP 1.0 and `Cache-Control` for HTTP 1.1.